# Images showing up in IE and Chrome, but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

This one has me stumped.  I'm not sure where to start on this one.

Images show up fine in IE, Chrome, and even my Android phone! What am I doing wrong?

This is all HTML & JQuery.  JQuery is dynamically populating the pieces on page load. (via an array in defaultRules.js)

Later, I will have fixed and redeployed this, images looked like this:

```
<img id="WhiteQueen" class="ui-widget-content ui-draggable" src="..\images\chessPieces\Chess.Merida\wq.png" style="z-index: 0; position: relative; ">
```

http://www.chessmangler.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the double dots prior to the folder name the images are stored in, also, take a look at the way your slashes are leaning!

Answer (score 2):

Try setting those '\' in the url paths to '/'

'\' is a windows thing. '/' is a www and all other OSes thing.

Comment: Yeah, just setting the first one in firebug fixed it for me. Always check your HTML first. It takes very little time and you'll waste a ton looking at JS if that's the problem.